# Resize output window of ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I am plotting few lat longs using ggmap and I get the output like this

[image]

I use the following code to generate this output, below code is part of the o/p

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

lat <- seq(31.26415,31.26831,0.00010)
lon <- seq(76.80890,76.82320,0.00015)
lon <- lon[seq(1,96.2)]
lon <- lon[1:42]
lat_long <- data.frame(lat,lon)

lat_median <- 31.26751
lon_median <- 76.82003

map <- get_map(location = c(lon_median, lat_median), maptype = "roadmap", zoom = 15)
ggmap(map) + 
  geom_path(data = lat_long, aes(), size = 2, lineend = "butt") + 
  geom_point(data = lat_long, color = "red3", size = 1)
```

My output window has lot of white space, which I could have used to show in the map. Can I increase this map output to better fit the window?

Comment: your code is not reproducible, lat, lon vectors have unequal lengths

Comment: I have updated the code. I copied it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `get_googlemap` function you can specify the dimensions and it doesn't have to be square e.g.:

```
map <- get_googlemap('paris', zoom = 15, size = c(500, 200), scale = 2)
```